# A bug in the site's pgn viewer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, pgn-viewer

I recently noticed a possible bug in the site's pgn viewer. I was reading the answers to the question in [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/shortest-game-with-18-queens) page. The first answer had a replayer. At one point of time when a pawn should capture a knight, the capturing move was not displayed correctly and it appeared as below:
[image: Instead of the pawn capturing the knight, both stay in the same square]

I moved back to the starting position and the knight and the pawn where displaced as you can see below:
[image: Pawn and knight displaced]

Is this a bug or is it simply because something is wrong with my browser?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug.  I fixed it in the github repo last year at some point, but apparently the version here hasn't been updated.

https://github.com/andrewphoy/chess-replayer/commit/f0d60d5329e855a91ebe70ffe4e931098fdf55bc

The issue is that any time there's a pawn move bxa6 it is incorrectly interpreted as an en passant capture which removes the piece at a5 but not at a6.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the player to latest (and sent you a pull request with a bugfix I had to make). This will be in the next build of the site.

Comment: The PGN viewer used in this site seems to have very limited features. Why don't we include features that are available in sites like chess.com?

Comment: @balpha looks awesome, thank you for updating it!