# Why are the pieces misaligned from the board?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, pgn-viewer

I recently pointed out a bug in the site's pgn viewer [here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/a-bug-in-the-sites-pgn-viewer) and it was told that it had been fixed. But now the pieces seem to be misaligned from the chess board as seen below.[image: Misaligned Pieces]

Why is this happening? Is it a bug again?

Comment: I can confirm this issue with the misaligned pieces. In the latest Firefox and Chrome. Interestingly, Internet Explorer 10 does not even show a board and just shows the FEN... text string.

Comment: I don't understand what this issue was, but my guess is that it was a caching issue.  The version of the pgn viewer was updated last week, and immediately afterwards I saw something similar, but after a few hard refreshes it was fixed.  It could be a cached css file, but at the very least you can try a hard refresh and see if that fixes things.

Comment: If you're still seeing this, let me know; otherwise, I'm gonna guess that @Andrew's right and it was some temporary caching thing.

Comment: @Shog9 I still have exactly the same problem as the OP is describing. Notice that the heading is missing for the game.

Comment: The problem is solved now (atleast, for me).

Comment: I still have the problem. I tried `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` (on Chrome), but it didn't help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Shog9 Hmm, I switched to Japanese encoding and back to Unicode again, and now the viewer is suddenly working!

Comment: Definitely sounds like some sort of stale cache then, @Dag. You should post that work-around as an answer, in case others are encountering this.

Answer (score 4):

I switched to Japanese encoding and back to Unicode again, and now the viewer is suddenly working!

I'm using Chrome.